# Warning: Missing argument 4 for renderForm()

Tags: php, html, mysql

Good morning/afternoon,

Can someone please explain to me why i keep getting a;

```
Warning: Missing argument 4 for renderForm(), called in /home/***/public_html/new.php
```

Here is the HTML/PHP code i am using;

```html
<?php

/*

NEW.PHP

Allows user to create a new entry in the database

*/



// creates the new record form

// since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable

function renderForm($date, $home, $time, $away, $city, $error)

{

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<title>New Record</title>

</head>

<body>

<?php

// if there are any errors, display them

if ($error != '')

{

echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';

}

?>



<form action="" method="post">

<div>

<label>Date:</label>
<input class="input" name="id" type="text" value="<?php echo $date; ?>">
<br/>

<label>Home Team:</label>
<input class="input" name="id" type="text" value="<?php echo $home; ?>">
<br/>

<label>Time:</label>
<input class="input" name="id" type="text" value="<?php echo $time; ?>">
<br/>

<label>Away Team:</label>
<input class="input" name="id" type="text" value="<?php echo $away; ?>">
<br/>

<label>Location:</label>
<input class="input" name="id" type="text" value="<?php echo $city; ?>">
<br/>


<p>* required</p>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</div>

</form>

</body>

</html>

<?php

}









// connect to the database

include('connect-db.php');



// check if the form has been submitted. If it has, start to process the form and save it to the database

if (isset($_POST['submit']))

{

// get form data, making sure it is valid

$date = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['date']));

$home = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['home']));

$time = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['time']));

$away = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['away']));

$city = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['city']));



// check to make sure both fields are entered

if ($date == '' || $home == '' || $time == '' || $away == '' || $city == '')

{

// generate error message

$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';



// if either field is blank, display the form again

renderForm($date, $home, $time, $away, $city, $error);

}

else

{

// save the data to the database

mysql_query("INSERT data SET date='$date', home='$home', time='$time', away='$away', city='$city'")

or die(mysql_error());



// once saved, redirect back to the view page

header("Location: view.php");

}

}

else

// if the form hasn't been submitted, display the form

{

renderForm('','','');

}

?>
```

I have tried to search here and google with no fix. Can anyone please help me please? This should be a form to add new events. But with these errors i am unable to make it work. Thank you in advance for any assistance you might be able to provide.

---

The original part is done. Thank you for all the answers. But now i after i submit it gives me this error, not sure if it has anything to do with the edit i made to:

```html
renderForm(null,null,null,null,null,null);
```

Thank you once again.

Comment: `renderForm('','','');` down the bottom of your code is missing a 4th argument.

Comment: Thank you for the right solution! Thank you!!

Comment: I suggest adding default values to your function itself, something like this: `function renderForm($date = '', $home = '', $time = '', $away = '', $city = '', $error = '')` - This will allow you to call `renderForm()` with no parameters to get a completely empty form.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says **[you may be at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)**. Learn about [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4712113/5827005). I recommend `PDO`, which I [wrote a class for](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO) to make it extremely easy, clean, and more secure than using non-parameterized queries. Also, [This article](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison) may help you choose between `MySQLi` and `PDO`

Comment: **Please**, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799), and `mysql_*` functions have been officially removed in PHP 7. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. If you can't decide, [this article will help to choose your best option](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: date in /home/***/public_html/new.php on line 114

Notice: Undefined index: home in /home/***/public_html/new.php on line 116

Notice: Undefined index: time in /home/***/public_html/new.php on line 118

Notice: Undefined index: away in /home/***/public_html/new.php on line 120

Notice: Undefined index: city in /home/***/public_html/new.php on line 122

Is this why i am getting this error now?

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

`renderForm('','','');` down the bottom of your code is missing a 4th argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is as follows:

```
function renderForm($date, $home, $time, $away, $city, $error){}
```

you require six total arguments to be passed to the function,

- $date
- $home
- $time
- $away
- $city
- $error

therefore you have to populate your function call with something for each of those

```
renderForm(null,null,null,null,null,null);
```

or you can use `''` the empty string you show in your example. But something has to be passed for each argument.